# Receive after result not returned

Tags: erlang

Given a function:

```
%% @doc Retrieves client's state.
-spec(state(pid()) -> atom()).
state(Pid) when is_pid(Pid) ->
  case process_info(Pid) of
    undefined ->
      undefined;
    _Else ->
      Pid ! {state, self()},
      receive
        {state, State} ->
          State
      after
        1000 ->
          undefined
      end
  end.
```

It works as expected for dead pids and for alive clients:

```
> client:state(A).
undefined
> client:state(Pid).
online
```

But for some reason returns Pid if process Pid will not reply his status during 1 second:

```
> client:state(self()).
<0.172.0>
```

I'm expecting 'undefined' atom there.
How can I fix this code?

Comment: Why do you expect `undefined` here? `process_info` returns some data for `self()`, not undefined, and then you send `{state, self()}` to the `self()` and receive it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you are receiving the message you sent. Your function is running on the shell process and sends itself the `{state, self()}` message. Right after sending the message, it receives the message and the function ends with `State`, which is the `self()` pid you sent.

I hope I've not been too confusing.